# Is it possible to change the userID of something like Fused Location Provider?

Tags: root-access, location-services, firewall, iptables

I have a bunch of apps bundled under userID on my stock rom, including **Fused Location Provider**. Since I'm using **AFWall+** to block said userID to block said apps - it also breaks my location detection for Osmand.

Is there any way for me to change the userID  it runs under? I have root available to me.

Comment: No. Fused Location always runs under system UID (1000).

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to change that? What launches it?

Comment: No. Android framework.

Comment: Okay, so nothing I can edit on live system even with root access? Hmm, what about system image editing offline and then installing that?